# How do you add a top level group in Password Safe?

Tags: passwords, password-management

Password Safe is an application to help you track all of the passwords you use at various sites. It's good, but there's one thing which I really struggle with. I want to add a top level group within Password Safe, like "Work", so that I can place within that the sites I log into for work, the passwords I use there, etc. Only thing is that, as far as I can determine, the only thing Password Safe allows me to do is select an existing group. And if I do and then issue the Add Group command, it puts that under the group I've selected. That is **not** what I want.

So how do I create a new group at the top level, in Password Safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe nobody figured out how easy it is.

1. Click on **View -> Collapse All** to make some free space.
2. If you have a lot of top-level groups so that there is no free space then maximize window
3. Now find the group you want to move to the top and drag it to free space.

Note that while dragging it may appear as if you're dragging it to the last group, but this is only a visual artifact! don't believe it.

Note also if there is another group with same name at the top level then the group being dragged will merge with existing one.

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I create a new group at the top level?

Right click in the empty space and click *Add Group*

[image]
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I am using Password Safe 3.35.01 and found the same problem. The other solutions I found (right clicking in whitespace / selecting a top level group and choosing Add Group from the Edit menu) did not work for me.

No matter what, I could not create a group at the top level, despite there already being many such groups in our team database.

In the end I simply chose Add Entry from the Edit menu, and then on the dialog I overwrote the Group name with my new Group name, and made a dummy entry. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop selected group to group "Work".

Comment: But i recommend use [KeePass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/?source=directory) instead of ugly and unfriendly Password Safe. You can export all your data from Password Safe to KeePass using XML export.

Comment: Sounds like I should give KeePass a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying KeePass and it does seem to be much easier to work with, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the 'empty' whitespace is difficult when your groups already appear to fill it. My solution is to maximise window and scroll as far as possible and click right at the very bottom, under the last entry. Right clicking anywhere else just brings up the dialogue box as it would right clicking on a group.
Not ideal but is a solution, hopefully this could be fixed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I've only found one fool-proof solution if you have so many groups that there is no whitespace you can click. Right-click an existing top-level group and click "Duplicate Group". Rename the new duplicate to the desired name. Add at least one new entry in this new group. Then delete all the entries you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Just got to "EDIT" then add "NEW ENTRY" then type in the "new group name" and fill out the rest of fields, and it will appear in the left hand side in the right order.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].